# Why is reload needed in this test setup? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are the associations:

```
Class Tree
  has_many :apples
end

Class Apple
  belongs_to :tree
end
```

This is my test setup code:

```
  let!(:apple) { create(:apple, tree: tree) }
  let(:tree) { create(:tree, :growing) }
```

In order for `tree.apples.first.apple_core` to not error out with something like `cannot call .apple_core on nil` or something, I need to do `tree.reload`. Why is this? It seems like the in memory tree should have the `has_many` association loaded in memory after the `let!` is called shouldn't it? I read the posts on `reload` and I'm still confused as to what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because in `apply` *Rspec* dont reload the `tree` but just use its `id`, so to get relation up-to-date you have to reload it forcely, and in case you have use *Factory girl* just do it in the after create handler:

```
 after(:create) do |item, evaluator|
    item.tree.reload
 end
```